# To build the program with a static lib, libcurl.lib

Tags: windows, visual-c++, static-libraries, cl.exe

I tried to build a stanalone program with a `static lib`, `libcurl.lib`. But I got bunch of errors.

I ever refered to the related posts on stackoverflow and libcurl homepage, unfortunately it is in vain so far.

The following is my building procedure and the error message I got.

Please comments.
Thank you a lot,

```
1. Build curl from source code
    nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=14  ENABLE_SSPI=no ENABLE_IPV6=no ENABLE_IDN=no GEN_PDB=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x64

2. Build main.obj CimXml.obj CimCurl.obj getpass.obj
    "cl -I.\include -DCURL_STATICLIB -EHsc -c main.cpp CimXml.cpp CimCurl.cpp getpass.cpp"

3. Build a "STATIC" library cimxml.lib  
    "lib CimXml.obj CimCurl.obj getpass.obj /out:cimxmlcurl.lib"

4. Build the alc.exe
    "cl -DCURL_STATICLIB -I.\include main.obj cimxmlcurl.lib libcurl_a.lib /link /LIBPATH:.\lib /verbose:lib /out:alc.exe"
```

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\nick\Documents\sblim-wbemcli-1.6.3-Beta>cl -DCURL_STATICLIB -I.\include main.obj cimxmlcurl .lib libcurl_a.lib /link /LIBPATH:.\lib /verbose:lib /out:alc.exe

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
/LIBPATH:.\lib
/nodefaultlib:MSVCRT.lib
/verbose:lib
/out:alc.exe
main.obj
cimxmlcurl.lib
libcurl_a.lib

Searching libraries
    Searching cimxmlcurl.lib:
    Searching .\lib\libcurl_a.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libcpmt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64\libucrt.lib:
    Searching cimxmlcurl.lib:
    Searching .\lib\libcurl_a.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libcpmt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:

Finished searching libraries

Searching libraries
    Searching cimxmlcurl.lib:
    Searching .\lib\libcurl_a.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libcpmt.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\LIBCMT.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\kernel32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64\libvcruntime.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64\libucrt.lib:

Finished searching libraries
    libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strdup imported in function curl_easy_init
    OLDNAMES.lib(strdup.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strdup imported
    libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol calloc imported in function curl_easy_init
    libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol free imported in function curl_easy_init
    libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol malloc imported in function curl_easy_init
    libcurl_a.lib(easy.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol realloc imported in function curl_easy_init
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strrchr imported in function Curl_strerror
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strrchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strerror imported in function Curl_strerror
    libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncpy imported in function Curl_strerror
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
    libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncpy imported
    libcurl_a.lib(strerror.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __sys_nerr imported in function Curl_strerror
    libcurl_a.lib(pingpong.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memmove imported in function sanitize_cookie_path
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
    libcurl_a.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol memmove imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_ntlm_msgs.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http_digest.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_output_digest
    libcurl_a.lib(dotdot.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_gethostname.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ldap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function file_do
    libcurl_a.lib(smb.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(pipeline.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(strtok.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(inet_pton.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(dict.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function Curl_cookie_add
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strchr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strchr imported in function _vsscanf_l
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
    libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function rtsp_do
    libcurl_a.lib(dotdot.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_dedotdotify
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_cookie_add
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strncmp imported
    libcurl_a.lib(connect.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function Curl_sndbufset
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strncmp imported in function curl_mprintf
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported in function Curl_cookie_init
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported in function _vsnprintf_l
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __acrt_iob_func imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fclose imported in function Curl_cookie_init
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
    libcurl_a.lib(netrc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fclose imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fgets imported in function Curl_cookie_init
    libcurl_a.lib(netrc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fgets imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fopen imported in function Curl_cookie_init
    libcurl_a.lib(netrc.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fopen imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function rtsp_do
    libcurl_a.lib(socks.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http_proxy.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function readwrite_data
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function _vsscanf_l
    libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported in function Curl_global_host_cache_init
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol qsort imported in function Curl_cookie_getlist
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http_proxy.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http_chunks.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoll imported in function Curl_chunked_strerror
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoll imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoll imported in function Curl_cookie_add
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
    libcurl_a.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoll imported
    libcurl_a.lib(asyn-thread.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _errno imported in function init_resolve_thread
    libcurl_a.lib(http_chunks.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _errno imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _errno imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
    libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol tolower imported in function Curl_cache_addr
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol tolower imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isalpha imported in function parse_proxy
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalpha imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalpha imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported in function parse_proxy
    libcurl_a.lib(escape.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isxdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strstr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strstr imported in function Curl_sasl_continue
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strstr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strstr imported in function parse_proxy
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strstr imported in function Curl_http_readwrite_headers
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strstr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strstr imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strpbrk imported in function parseurlandfillconn
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fwrite imported in function Curl_init_userdefined
    libcurl_a.lib(sendf.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol fwrite imported
    libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(smtp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtol imported in function parse_proxy
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(pipeline.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtol imported in function Curl_pipeline_penalized
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtol imported
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strtoul imported in function parseurlandfillconn
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoul imported
    libcurl_a.lib(escape.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strtoul imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(smtp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isdigit imported in function Curl_ftp_parselist
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isdigit imported in function dprintf_DollarString
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(imap.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isdigit imported
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fputc imported in function curl_mfprintf
    libcurl_a.lib(mprintf.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf imported in function _vsnprintf_l
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http_digest.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_ntlm.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isspace imported in function Curl_sasl_continue
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isspace imported in function Curl_add_custom_headers
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isspace imported
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memchr imported in function Curl_http_readwrite_headers
    libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol memchr imported in function tftp_connect
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fseek imported in function Curl_readrewind
    libcurl_a.lib(progress.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol fflush imported in function Curl_pgrsUpdate
    libcurl_a.lib(strequal.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol stricmp imported in function curl_strequal
    OLDNAMES.lib(stricmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol stricmp imported
    libcurl_a.lib(strequal.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol strnicmp imported in function curl_strnequal
    OLDNAMES.lib(strnicmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol strnicmp imported
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isalnum imported in function parsedate
    libcurl_a.lib(rtsp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
    libcurl_a.lib(ftplistparser.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isalnum imported
    libcurl_a.lib(telnet.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol atoi imported in function check_telnet_options
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _lseeki64 imported in function file_do
    libcurl_a.lib(getenv.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol getenv imported in function GetEnv
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_sasl.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isupper imported in function Curl_sasl_decode_mech
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol isupper imported
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_ntlm_core.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol toupper imported in function Curl_ntlm_core_mk_ntlmv2_hash
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol islower imported in function loop
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isprint imported in function loop
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_fnmatch.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol isgraph imported in function loop
    OLDNAMES.lib(strdup.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _strdup imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _read imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _write imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(stricmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _stricmp imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(strnicmp.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _strnicmp imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _close imported
    OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _open imported
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputs referenced in function cookie_output
    libcurl_a.lib(ftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_ntlm_core.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(cookie.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(hostip.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(http.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(tftp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__time64
    libcurl_a.lib(url.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fread referenced in function Curl_init_userdefined
    libcurl_a.lib(transfer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fread
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fread
    libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_read referenced in function curlx_read
    OLDNAMES.lib(read.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_read
    libcurl_a.lib(warnless.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_write referenced in function curlx_write
    OLDNAMES.lib(write.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_write
    libcurl_a.lib(parsedate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gmtime64 referenced in function Curl_gmtime
    libcurl_a.lib(curl_threads.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__beginthreadex referenced in function Curl_thread_create
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_close referenced in function file_done
    OLDNAMES.lib(close.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_close
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_open referenced in function file_connect
    OLDNAMES.lib(open.obi) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_open
    libcurl_a.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fstat64 referenced in function file_do
    libcurl_a.lib(smb.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__getpid referenced in function smb_format_message
    libcurl_a.lib(formdata.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__stat64 referenced infunction AddFormData
    alc.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
```

Comment: When you use /nodefaultlib:MSVCRT.lib then you are just trying to hide a rather nasty build problem under the floor mat.  Doesn't work, jumps up and bytes you in the rear end anyway.  All code and libraries must be built with the same setting, either /MT or /MD.

Comment: Accoring to the Makefile.vc14 for curl-7.45, I am sure I tried the same option, /MT, for my program and libcurl but no luck as well.

Comment: Doubtful, I don't see you use /MT in your cl.exe invocations.  The default is /MD, the "always safe" selection.  You are shooting your leg off by hacking these build commands by hand btw, not taking advantage of the debugging features is never not a mistake.  Do this with a project in the IDE instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't dig it out from the commands history like Linux. I just try again as below: 1. cl /MT -I.\include -DCURL_STATICLIB -EHsc -c main.cpp  CimXml.cpp CimCurl.cpp getpass.cpp ;  2. lib CimXml.obj CimCurl.obj getpass.obj /out:cimxmlcurl.lib; 3. cl /MT -DCURL_STATICLIB -I.\include main.obj cimxmlcurl.lib libcurl_a.lib /link /LIBPATH:.\lib /out:alc.exe. It is the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure it out finally.
I have to use:

- "nmake RTLIBCFG=static /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=14
  ENABLE_IPV6=no ENABLE_IDN=no GEN_PDB=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x64" in the
  first step

  and to
- compile with /MT option for every steps using "cl.exe" like Hans
  Passant commented.

  Hopefully, this can help out people suffering in the same issue.
  Bby the way, I found a the website with similar solution as below, http://www.chipkin.com/building-libcurl-on-windows-with-mt-and-mtd/.